# Error adding MixedCollection component to extjs form

Tags: javascript, dynamic, extjs, extjs4.1

I am trying to dynamically build a extjs form and when I try to add the dynamically built MixedCollection object to the form I get a **TypeError: e.mixins.elementCt is undefined** error.

```
<div id="form-@pageSpecificVar" class="grid-container even"></div>
<script>

    Ext.define('HeaderForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;
            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                id: Ext.id(),
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Test'
                    }]
                }]
            });
            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    // Define our data model
    Ext.define('HeaderModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'FieldA', type: 'int' }
        ]
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'HeaderModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: { create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST' },
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Test/Header")',
            timeout: 1200000,
        listeners: {
            load: function () {
            }
        }
        }
    });

    store.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                var form = new HeaderForm();
                var formItems = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
                Ext.each(records[0].fields.items, function (item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    formItems.add(new Ext.form.DisplayField({
                        fieldLabel: 'Test'
                    }));
                }, this);
                console.log(formItems);
                form.add(formItems);
                form.loadRecord(records[0].data);
                form.render('form-@pageSpecificVar');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Another thing I don't understand is, when I put the function inside the load listener, nothing happens.  So I had to resort to using the callback event.

**Update:** 
form.add method takes a component or component array, so instead of adding MixedCollection type I refer to formItems.items to add the array of displayfields components.

<strike>But for some reason the store listeners load is not getting triggered when store.load is executed, does anyone see a problem with that?</strike>
Nevermind this... I figured out... I placed the listener instead of the proxy instead of the store.

**Q2**

<strike>Also something weird is that during the callback method of store.load, the records is not return with the loaded values.</strike>
Nevermind this... I figured out... It was the json object I'm passing.  Forgot to take it out of the error/data structure for form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MixedCollection isn't an accepted parameter for add, you need to use an array. This info is in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @Evan I fixed by refering to formItems.items